# Insert image in html page

Tags: html

I have a html page and like to insert a image.
I have the following html code:

```
 <img src="../Images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" height="50">
```

I decided to take "../Images/logo.jpg" as source because my logo.jpg is located in the folder two levels up from the current folder in the folder Images.
But it can't find the picture, when I look at the website.
What would be the right src for my image and why?
Thanks for your help!

[image]

Edit:
I fixed my problem by add to my class Startup.cs the following code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
      Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Styles")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/Styles")
    });
}
```

Comment: the relative path needs to be relative to the url (not the file) - I'm guessing that as it's your homepage, that would be `./images`.  Try replacing the dots with a tilda (if this is mvc) - `~/images/logo.jpg`

Comment: try this `<img src="./Images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" height="50">`

Comment: When I open the page in my browser my url is just "https://localhost:44321" and it can't find anything under the url https://localhost:44321//Images/logo.jpg.

Comment: you have a double slash there - have you tried using the tilda?

Comment: Moving comments up here - your server is iis, click on your site and then in the right pane click on mime types and make sure jpg and css are included.  If they are you need to post your updated code and show us what changes you made to the src - also did you try browsing to the image without the double slash?

Comment: Without the double slash and a tilde it neither works. It always can't find the file. I don't have my site in the iis, because I just test it with iis express in visual studio. Can I look there for the mime types too?

Comment: I find the mime-types in the applicationhost.config file and there are also .jpg and .css

Answer (score 1):

Going back once with ../ will lead you to your view directory, you have to go back once and then go to Images like so :

```
<img src="../../Images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" height="50">
```

Comment: Can't believe this has been upvoted 3 times, the site is an asp.net mvc site and the index file won't be run under that url, it will most likely be the home page so going up 2 directories from the root url will not serve the image.  Relative image urls are relative to the url serving it - not the file it is in

Comment: I was under the impression that it should work, I will gladly delete my answer once OP answered about what is working or not

Comment: @Pete you're right. The solution didn't work for me. I get in the console the message "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" and it also doesn't find my style.css, etc. How do I have to handle this for a asp.net mvc site?

Comment: Is your server set up to serve those types of files?

Comment: @Pete what is my server here or how can I let my server serve this type of files?